# Where I am going for vacations?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, wordplay, language

> "Yes we can"
>
> More personal
>
> In another language

Which country am I going to for vacations?

Hint 1:

> Three countries involved in the riddle (not talking about the destination yet) are/were very close to the destination to some extend. Two of them have been major foes for quite a few years.

Hint 2:

> Play with simple sounds

Hint 3:

> Let us be more affirmative, in a third language

Comment: My first contribution, not sure it deserves your brains

Comment: Is the answer in english, or 'in another language'?

Comment: The answer is part english, part another language, and give you a country name

Comment: Country is in Europe, I presume??

Comment: @Sid No it is not. I just arrived.

Comment: I might ask for a hint, since I want this puzzle solved!

Comment: @IAmInPLS Done. I can add a couple of others

Comment: Hint 1 could mean USA and Russia(But they are too far from each other) or India and Pakistan(Not exactly major foes)

Comment: @Sid Maybe they are close by size, not by distance. Just a guess

Comment: That is a possibility...But, I think he meant distance...

Comment: USA and Russia are/were not so far away in the history

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you are going to :

> Canada

"Yes we can" :

> I just disassembled the sentence.
>  
>  In french, "yes" = "oui" which is phonetically equal to "we".
>  
>  "CAN" is the code of a country where official language is french : Canada!

"More personal" :

> As stated in the comments, initially the sentence was "Yes I can a "da"", with "I" more personal than the "we".

Hint 1 :

> Three countries involved in the riddle : you are talking about USA, France and Russia/URSS, who were allies during the World War II. Also, URSS and USA have been foes for a few years.

Hint 2 :

> Simple sounds refer to "we" = "oui", and "can", which gives the beginning of the country. Also...

Hint 3 :

> ..."Yes" in russian is "да", which is said "da" and so represents the end of Cana*DA*.

Comment: Initially the sentence that came to my mind was "Yes I can a "da", with "I" more personal than the "we". Russia is at least involved in the "да".

Comment: Ok, I will edit to reflect that! I knew I was missing something on the "more personal"

Comment: Canada is bordered by the USA and Alaska and France (through Saint-Pierre et Miquelon). Alaska used to be a russian territory.  First Nations probably came, at least partly, through Bering Strait.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to guess

> Casablanca, Morocco

Yes we can

> Was USA President Barack Obama's campaign slogan in 2008. Mr. Obama lives in the White House. "White House" in Spanish is "Casa blanca".

More personal

> Might refer to the Moors, who populated North Africa including Morocco

In another language

> See spoiler block #2

Hint 1

> Spain and France are close to Morocco, but USA is not.

Comment: That could be it, +1

Comment: @shoover Pretty clever. Your answer relies a lot on the name of a specific city, instead of a country.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to...

> Italy

"Yes we can"

> If you translate "Yes we can" from english to latin you obtain "**ita**, possumus"

More personal

> If you translate "More personal" from english to latin you obtain "personale" which is an italian word

In another language

> The other language is clearly latin

Comment: Almost the same path that the one I traveled (for the puzzle). When the riddle is found, I'll share a joke joining Italy and the country I am going to.

Comment: So, what is the difference between Montréal (Canada) and  Florence (Italy)? In Montréal, many women are named Florence (sorry, but I promised)

Answer (score 2):

My theory is you shall visit:

> Switzerland

Yes we can

> In french, yes is oui which is pronounced we. Cannes is pronounced can and is a place in france.
>  Stever indicates this could also point to *Ita*ly from the Latin translation into *ita*, possumus"

More personal

> Moors inhabited sicily which reinforces the Italy connection

In another language

> My suspicion is this will lead to German and Austria , in french the phrase has the word "autre" but that isn't quite Austia... My theorem is it is the country around Switzerland (minus Austria...). Quite Frankly safe to say I didn't solve it dead on but maybe someone can build on it.

Comment: As a french, I thought this at the beginning, but OP said in comment that it was not in Europe...

Comment: @IAmInPLS Do Swiss(es) believe they are in Europe :) The reasoning is very close to mine, and you gave an important hint I was holding (in your spoiler block #2)

Answer (score 1):

I think You're going in:

> USA

"Yes we can"

> You can find this on Youtube, Barack Obama's Song.
>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjXyqcx-mYY

"More Personal"

> In the USA there are society like CIA, NASA. They have a lot of secrets, they are more personal and safe.

"In another language"

> ! In the USA the official language is English, 20% of people speak another language (Combined total of all languages
>   other than English).

Comment: You are at the same time the closest and the farthest. I like the joke: "what is the second language spoken in California?" "english...".